# Flickering CSS Submenu

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Wordpress Principal Menu and Submenu. The dropdown flikers a lot an disappear when i hover over it. What's going wrong and how can I fix it?

PRODUCTO > CLICLISMO

```css
#menu-item-3083 .nav-column-links {
  display: none;
}

#menu-item-3083 a:hover+.nav-column-links,
#menu-item-3083 a {
  display: block !important;
}

#menu-item-3083 .nav-column-links {
  position: absolute;
  left: 32em;
  top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<li id="menu-item-3083" class="menu-item-3083">
  <a href="http://spiuk.mx/product-category/textiles-ciclismo/">Ciclismo &gt;</a>
  <div class="nav-column-links">
    <ul>
      <li id="menu-item-3643" class="menu-item-3643"><a href="http://spiuk.mx/producto/elite-bib-short-hombre/">Elite Bib Short Hombre</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-3644" class="menu-item-3644"><a href="http://spiuk.mx/producto/elite-jersey-hombre/">Elite Jersey Hombre</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-3645" class="menu-item-3645"><a href="http://spiuk.mx/producto/performance-bib-short-mujer/">Performance Bib Short Mujer</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-3646" class="menu-item-3646"><a href="http://spiuk.mx/producto/performance-jersey-mujer/">Performance Jersey Mujer</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Chrome 51.0 (Windows)

Comment: Im sory for the code. The website is this: spiuk.mx, http://i.imgur.com/4Qz2ccS.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `#menu-item-3083 a:hover + .nav-column-links, #menu-item-3083 a`
to

```
#menu-item-3083:hover .nav-column-links, #menu-item-3083 a {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Do this for all the other menus:
`#menu-item-3083 a:hover +` becomes `#menu-item-3083:hover`